# Using populate to get reference document, but it is returning the full document in an array of 1

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Whenever I call the client, it displays the full json of the client document in client[0]. I want to be able to call work.client.name and work.client.url and such. Sorry if this is a duplicate question, I searched long and hard and never found an answer.

The work controller

```
exports.work_detail = function(req, res, next) {

    async.parallel({
        work: function(callback) {
            Work.findById(req.params.id)
                .populate('client')
                .exec(callback);
        }
    }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (results.work==null) { // No results.
            var err = new Error('Work not found');
            err.status = 404;
            return next(err);
        }
        // Successful, so render.
        console.log(results.work.client.name);
        res.render('work/work_detail', { title: 'Work Details', work:  results.work } );
    });

};
```

The work model

```
var workSchema = new Schema({
    client: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client', required: true }],
    time: {
        type: Number,
    },
    work_done: {
        type: Array,
    },
    work_value: {
        type: [{}],
    },
    total: {
        type: Number,
        // set: calculateValue
    },
    work_address: {
        type: String,
    },
    note: {
        type: String,
    }
    }, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

The client model

```
var clientSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        set: firstToUpper
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        set: firstToUpper
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    phone: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        lowercase: true
    },
    note: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    }}, {
    timestamps: true,
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
});

// Capitalize first letter of each word when called
function firstToUpper (string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

// Virtual for client's full name
clientSchema
.virtual('name')
.get(function () {
    return this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name;
});
// Virtual for clients's URL
clientSchema
.virtual('url')
.get(function () {
    return '/invoice/client/' + this._id
});
```

Comment: `client` is defined in your schema as an array. If you expect only one result then don't define it as an array. i.e `client: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client', required: true }`. You get an array because that's what you told it to store as.

Comment: Is there any way to define it as something other than an array? I haven't seen it done any other way

Comment: That's what I just showed you how to do. You need to actually "store" the documents like that though. Your current documents will now all have an array of one member, so you need to rewrite all of them to a single value.

Comment: Oh, I see! I didn't notice you didn't include the brackets. I've spent a good portion of my day on this and you see it instantly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema was wrapped in array on accident, pointed out by Neil Lunn